# Update ApexChart realtime with Vaadin Flow

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, esp8266, vaadin-flow, openjdk-11

the code that I will present now, is made with vaadin and the ApexChart addon, I simply want to update the line-type graph in real time, I have the `@Push` annotation in the MainView and a ScheduledExecutorService that runs every second

**Vaadin version** is `14.1.27`

**Apexcharts Addon**

```xml
    <dependency>
       <groupId> com.github.appreciated </groupId>
       <artifactId> apexcharts </artifactId>
       <version> 2.0.0.beta9 </version>
    </dependency>
```

**Apache Tomcat/9.0.27**

I make a simple request, then within the `access(()-> )` method, finally invokes `chart.updateSeries()`

**Code**

```java
    public void updateChar() {
  
         final ApexCharts chart = ApexChartsBuilder.get().withChart(ChartBuilder.get()
                    .withType(Type.line)
                    .withAnimations(AnimationsBuilder.get()
                            .withEnabled(true)
                            .withEasing(Easing.linear)
                            .withDynamicAnimation(DynamicAnimationBuilder.get()
                                    .withSpeed(1000)
                                    .build())
                            .build())
                    .build())
                    .withDataLabels(DataLabelsBuilder.get()
                            .withEnabled(false)
                            .build())
                    .withSeries(new Series<>(0))
                    .withXaxis(XAxisBuilder.get()
                            .withCategories()
                            .withMax(10.0)
                            .build())
                    .build();
     
           chart.setHeight("400px");
           chart.setWidth("400px");
    
           schedule.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                    try {
                        final CompletableFuture<String> cf = HttpClient
                                .newBuilder()
                                .build()
                                .sendAsync(HttpRequest
                                                .newBuilder(new URI(HUMIDITY))
                                                .GET()
                                                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                                                .build(),
                                        HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                                .thenApplyAsync(HttpResponse::body);
                        cf.whenCompleteAsync((data, error) -> {
                            if (getUI().isEmpty()) return;
                            if (Objects.nonNull(error)) {
                                cf.completeExceptionally(error);
                                getUI().get().access(() -> {
                                    Notification.show("Error: " + error);
                                });
                            } else {
                                if (getUI().isEmpty()) return;
                                getUI().get().access(() -> {
                                    final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
                                    final Series<Double> series = new Series<>(25.2, 30.2, 25.77, 45.66, 60.00, 55.5);
                                    final Series<Double> serie1 = new Series<>(30.3, 34.10, 20.11, 12.15, 55.66, 82.5, 64.35, 100.4, 77.66, 14.32, 25.77);
                                    final Series<Double> serie2 = new Series<>(25.5, 55.3, 44.5, 99.6, 10.3, 44.6, 36.6);
                                    final Series[] randomSeries = new Series[]{series, serie1, serie2, series};
                                    //chart.updateSeries(radomSeries[SECURE_RANDOM.nextInt(randomSeries .length)]);
        
                                    chart.updateSeries(new Series<>(data));
                                });
        
                            }
                        }, EXEC)
                                .join();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException();
                    }
                }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }
```

unfortunately the result is not as expected, with the same code, I am able to update `TextFields`

---

[image: Dry Paint]

---

Updated

The current solution I have, is to use list to store the Timestamps and double values ​​of the sensors.

this [constant](https://github.com/rucko24/nodemcu-with-flow/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/application/backend/services/charts/ApexChartService.java#L65) is very important for resolution in seconds.

---

Also under background I use `WebClient` and changed the default [configuration](https://github.com/rucko24/nodemcu-with-flow/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/application/backend/configuration/SensorWebClientBuilderConfiguration.java) of reactor-netty to retry every 2 seconds.

```java
@Bean
public WebClient sensorWebClientBuilder(final WebClient.Builder webClient) {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create() 
          .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000)
            .doOnConnected((Connection connection) ->
                 connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
    return webClient
          .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)) 
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build();
}
```

[image]

- [source](https://github.com/rucko24/nodemcu-with-flow/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/application/backend/services/charts/ApexChartService.java)